# Scope of a function variable

Tags: python, function, scope

I have the following function saved as dummy_function.py

```
def abc():

    return q*q
```

On the Python console, I run

```
from dummy_function import *
q=4
b=abc()
```

I get the following error:
`NameError: name 'q' is not defined`

I understand that even though I have defined q in my current environment, it doesn't belong in the scope of the function abc. My question is how to solve this. I cannot define q in dummy_function. It will be in my current program but I have to run imported customized code on variables in the current program.

Comment: why not pass ``q`` to your function as a parameter?

Comment: This is just a raw example. I am passing a data-frame to the imported function but the range of the column value is available only in the current program. So if I say, xyz(df.iloc[:,range]), it says range not defined even though I have passed df as an argument in the function building

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni I am not understanding why you cannot just  pass `range` to your function?

Comment: raw examples get raw answers. how should we help you if you do not provide a [mcve]? your approach still sounds like a bad design choice to me. imported modules should not rely on magical global variables from the main program.

Comment: Anyway, what you are essentially asking for is dynamic scoping, but python (and pretty much all modern languages) use lexical scope. The sane way of doing this is to pass the values you need as arguments to the function.

Comment: range is not a number or python xrange. It's a variable sed. Say sed=1 it should pick first column. But sed is computed in the current program not in the imported one

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni yes, I understand that you do not mean the built-in `range` but *again*, what is stopping you from *passing it as an argument to the function?*

Comment: When I pass I get name error.

Comment: **what name error**? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

You should put a parameter that your function will receive:

```
def abc(q):
    return q*q
```

Then when you run your function, you should put what number you want the function to execute:

```
q = 4
print(abc(q))
```

Or you can do

```
print(abc(4))
```

Comment: You can also define a default value of q in the abc function